# Кастомный фильтр контента UITableView на UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

Нужен кастомный элемент (кнопка-фильтр) на `UINavigationBar`, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку выпадал список с чекбоксами в виде `popup` окошка.
В зависимости от выбраных чекбоксов фильтруется контент в `UITableView`: все элементы, прочитанные, непрочитанные, закладки и т. д. Уверен, что есть готовая библиотека в cocoapods, но не нашел её.

Подскажите, с помошью каких контролов можно написать этот элемент?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, точно стандартных нет, так как это не iPhone стайл. Если брать iPad, то есть класс `UIPopoverPresentationController`. Что касается сторонних либ, то cocoapods - это просто библиотеки, а превьюхи тут искали: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popup ?
А я еще юзаю ActionSheet.